# How return "int" value in a template c++, with strings as parameters

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ for the first time.
I want to develop a template to calculate `length` of a `const char*, char[]`  without having to redefine the same function.

I have tried,

```
template <class N> N length(N str){
    int pos = 0;
    while (str[pos] != '\0'){pos++;}
    return pos; 
}
```

But I got an error, since I should return `N class`. Can I fix this?

Comment: FWIW, both a pointer and an array argument will work with a `const char*` parameter. No need for a template there. There's also `std::string` and `std::string_view`, which have functions to get their length (among many other useful features).

Comment: You can just make your function return an `int`, it doesn't have to return an `N` just because it's templated over `class N`.

Comment: If `str` is a `const char*`, what should the return type be? If `str` is a `std::string` instance, what should the return type be? Do you see a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions to do that but if you want to use templates, here is a function.

Note that u return `N` and u ask how to solve this problem while u should return `size_t`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
constexpr size_t length(const char (&arr) [N]){
    return N-1;
}
int main(){
    char arr [3] = "me";
    std::cout << length(arr) << " " << length("me");
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zavs4c)

Note that this template won't work if `\0` is not at the end of the characters array and won't work with `char*` as @errorikta has mentioned.

It's just for practice. to know the size of those strings use [`std::strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) from `<cstring>` and you can see a possible implementation in the attached link.

Comment: What if the array is `char arr [42] = "me";`? You might also want to clarify that this template does not work with a pointer to char.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to develop a template to calculate length of a `const char*`, `char[]` without having to redefine the same function.

`char[]` will implicitly convert to a `const char*`, so you don't need a template. It is sufficient to write a function that accepts a `const char*`. Also, such function exists in the standard library so there is no need to write the function except for exercise purposes.

> But I got an error, since I should return N class.

Your `return` statement has the type `int`, which makes sense for returning a length. But you've declared that the function returns `N` object instead. This does not make sense for a function that is supposed to return a length. Solution: Declare the function to return an integer type. `std::size_t` is conventionally used for array / string lengths.